# How to extract text between parentheses in window caption in Word macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a scenario where I will have many Word documents with a title that contains text within parentheses which I wish to extract and manipulate. The title bar info (which is not the same as the actual document name) looks something like this:

Random-length text (LAST NAME, FIRST NAME MI) Random-length text

I have experimented with the Left, Right, and Mid functions, but I'm getting mixed results. The only way the Mid function will work is if I determine the exact position and length of the text, but my results have been inconsistent. I can't seem to hone in on JUST the text between the parens - no more, no less.

So far the only success I've had is with two separate macros that work perfectly to get EITHER the text to the left of the right parenthesis OR the text to the right of the left parenthesis. How can I get all of the text in one step?

---

Here are my two "working" macros, FWIW:

```
Sub a1FullNameDiscardAfterRightParen()

'Discard text after right paren (including paren)

  Dim strFullName As String
  Dim BRP As Long 'ARP=after right paren
  strFullName = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption
  ARP = InStr(strFullName, Chr(41))

  If ARP > 0 Then
     strFullName = Left(strFullName, ARP - 1)
  End If

  Selection.TypeText strFullName

End Sub
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub a2FullNameDiscardBeforeLeftParen()

'Discard text before left paren (including paren)

  Dim strFullName As String
  Dim BLP As Long 'BLP=before left paren
  strFullName = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption
  BLP = InStr(strFullName, Chr(41))

  If BLP > 0 Then
     strFullName = Right(strFullName, BLP - 1)
  End If

  Selection.TypeText strFullName

End Sub
```

Comment: Your description is overly-broad for a simple problem: "Extract text between parentheses". Reduce your question and it will more valuable for others having a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, JimiLoe. I have shortened my original question. :)  Meanwhile, vacip's answer works perfectly, so I'm a happy camper!

Comment: Note that Jimi wasn't talking about question *length*, but about how much ground you cover in your question. At any rate, your question is clear enough, your focus is on a specific string where there are two parentheses so I reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, here is a code that extracts everything between the parenthesis. You want to use the mid() function.

```
Sub ExtractTextBetweenParenthesis()

Dim MyText As String
Dim OpenPosition As Integer
Dim closeposition As Integer

OpenPosition = InStr(ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption, "(")
closeposition = InStr(ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption, ")")

MyText = Mid(ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption, OpenPosition + 1, closeposition - OpenPosition - 1)

Selection.TypeText MyText

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, vacip - Wow, your solution works PERFECTLY. I am a happy camper. THANK YOU SO, SO MUCH for your quick and helpful response! :)